# Showing that $3$ splits completely in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{7}, \sqrt{19})$.

Tags: proof-verification, algebraic-number-theory

Let $K = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{7}, \sqrt{19})$, $L = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{7})$, and $M = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{19})$.  Then we have that $3\mathcal{O}_L = \langle\sqrt{7} + 2 \rangle\langle2-\sqrt{7} \rangle$ and $3\mathcal{O}_M = \langle 4-\sqrt{19} \rangle\langle \sqrt{19} + 4\rangle$.  Now, if $3\mathcal{O}_K = \mathfrak{P}_1^{e_1}\dots \mathfrak{P}_g^{e_g}$, since $G = \text{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q}) \cong C_2 \times C_2$ and the decomposition groups $Z(\mathfrak{P_i})$ are conjugate to each other, it follows that $Z(\mathfrak{P}_i) = Z(\mathfrak{P_j})$ for each $i,j$.  Therefore, we may denote $Z = Z(\mathfrak{P}_i)$.   Let $\sigma, \tau \in G$ such that $\sigma: \sqrt{7} \mapsto - \sqrt{7}$ and $\tau : \sqrt{19} \mapsto - \sqrt{19}$, and observe that $\langle \sigma, \tau\rangle = G$.  Because $3$ splits in $M$ and $L$, it must be that $2 \mid g = [G:Z]$ so that $Z \neq G$.  Suppose that $g = 2$.  Then the fixed field $K_Z$ for $Z$ must either be $M$, $L$, or $F = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{133})$.  We also have that $3\mathcal{O}_F = \langle\sqrt{133}, 3 \rangle\langle \sqrt{133}-1 ,3\rangle$.  Now, if we pick a $\mathfrak{P}_i$, looking at the ways $3$ can split in the degree $2$ sub-extensions implies that every element of $G$ moves one of the $\mathfrak{P}_i$.  For example, if $\mathfrak{P_i} \cap K_Z = \langle 2 + \sqrt{7}\rangle$, then $\sigma(\mathfrak{P}_i)\cap K_Z = \langle 2 - \sqrt{7}\rangle$, and $\sigma(\mathfrak{P}_i) \neq \mathfrak{P}_i$.  So none of the degree $2$ sub-extensions can be the fixed field for $Z$, and therefore $Z$ is trivial.

I think this is the right idea, but I'm having a little trouble explaining the part about every element of $G$ moving one of the $\mathfrak{P_i}$.  Is there a better way to do this?  I have a bad feeling that I'm overcomplicating this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The decomposition group of a Galois subfield is the image of the decomposition group of the larger field. Hence, if $Z$ has order $2$, then the decomposition group of (exactly) two of the quadratic subfields also have order two, which contradicts that $3$ splits in $L$ and $M$. (More generally, if $p$ splits completely in two fields $L$ and $M$ it splits in their compositum.)

Comment: @user670344  So if $\mathfrak{p} = \mathfrak{P} \cap \mathcal{O}_L$, and $3 = \mathfrak{P} \cap \mathbb{Q}$, then you're saying $Z(\mathfrak{p}) \cong \pi(Z(\mathfrak{P}))$, with $\pi: G \to \text{Gal}(L/\mathbb{Q}) \cong G/H$ ($H$ is the subgroup fixing $L$).  In general, don't you need $H$ to be normal in $G$?

Comment: First sentence: Yes this is correct (this statement only makes sense if $H$ is Galois). My last comment is related to the fact that a prime $p$ splits completely in a field $L$ if and only if it splits completely in the Galois closure of $L$. To prove all of these statements you need to draw diagrams of the fields together with the completions of these fields at the relevant various primes then think about the Galois correspondence.